# docker hub: interpreting layers to understand what is already installed

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile, docker-registry

I have started using docker frequently recently. I usually pull an image from dockerhub or write a Dockerfile based on a dockerhub image.

Is there a way to know what is already in the image (obviously without pulling the image) like what OS it is built on, if python, pip is installed, if some python library like NumPy is installed or not?

For example: this image https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/2.6.0rc0-gpu

From the tag, I can know that it has tensorflow with cuda (gpu) support. But no other info is provided.

I recently figured out, I can click each layer, to see the actual code. But it actually takes some digging around to find more details.

For example: I saw some `apt` commands to figure out it is based on debian/ubuntu OS. Or, after reading the `python3-pip` keyword from the image, I realized `pip` is installed.

The code is not very readable (to me at least). Is there a better way to figure what is already in the image to avoid redundant installation in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always find the dockerfile of the image that you're interested in. For example, you can find all layers of, for example, image python:3.9 [here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.9/alpine3.13/Dockerfile)

Or you can use `docker history` to view all layers of one image.

Docker (brilliantly) use previous layers for a new build, and this is also primary difference from virtual machine. For example, you can pull a python image:

```
docker pull python:3.6
```

Take a quick look at images available with `docker image ls` you can find an image id like this

`python       3.6       5fad76530472   7 days ago           875MB`

Then create a new dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "something"]
```

The image python is already downloaded at `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` so when you run it with `docker build -f dockerfile .`, you can see:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon     47MB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> 5fad76530472
Step 2/2 : ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "test"]
 ---> Running in b7034642a88d
Removing intermediate container b7034642a88d
 ---> 0a6f3dc9d10a
Successfully built 0a6f3dc9d10a
```

The image id of Python is exactly the same, which means Docker doesn't restart everything from scratch, but instead, reuse the image already available.

If you go to the directory `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`, and run

```
$ du -sh -m overlay2
1087 overlay2
```

This means the total size of data for is about 1087 MBs, but if you run `docker image ls` and sum up the total size of all images, it is much bigger! We can say that there is some sort of intelligent mechanics for storing Docker images and that we cannot simply imply that all the sizes of the Docker images equal retrieve the real storage size.

Hopefully, this addresses partly your concerns about redundant images in Dockerfile.